# Browser requests not working but curl does with apache2 proxy

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy

I'm trying to configure apache2 for my server. I got tomcat server on 8080 port. And i want apache2 to proxying all my request.
When i do **`curl http://localhost/site`** apache works. I have this in log. When i do **`curl http://examotive.xxx.com/site`** (this url is external for my app) apache works too. I have this in log. 
But when i trying to get **`http://examotive.xxx.com/site`** from my browser apache doesn't work. Browser request going directly to tomcat. And i got this request in tomcat access.log.
This is my apache2 for proxying config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com
```

ServerName examotive.xxx.com

ProxyPreserveHost Off

#INCLUDE THE EXTRA PROXYPASS RULE FOR /site HERE

```
ProxyPass /site/ http://localhost:8080/site/
  ProxyPass /site http://localhost:8080/site/
  ProxyPass /cms/ http://localhost:8080/cms/
  ProxyPass /cms http://localhost:8080/cms/
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/site/
  ProxyPassReverse /site/ http://localhost:8080/site/
  ProxyPassReverse /site http://localhost:8080/site/
  ProxyPassReverse /cms/ http://localhost:8080/cms/
  ProxyPassReverse /cms http://localhost:8080/cms/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/site/
```

ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /

`# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>`

Where is problem?